# Scroll to the selected tab if the selected tab is hidden in p:tabview on initial tabview load

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tabs, tabview

Assume that there are many tabs are there in `p:tabview` and scroll is being shown to navigate to all the tabs.

If the active tab whose contents are shown is the right most tab then it is not visible to the user on initial `p:tabview` load. If we navigate to the right most using scroll button then we could see the active tab highlighted indicating it is selected tab.

How to scroll to the active tab on load so that user able to see the selected tab always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the following way by overriding `initScrolling` method in primefaces `p:tabview` component JavaScript file i.e. tabview.js file.

```
  initScrolling: function() {
      if(this.jq.is(':visible')) {
          var overflown = (this.lastTab.position().left - this.firstTab.position().left) >                                               
                           this.navscroller.innerWidth();
          if(overflown) {
            this.navscroller.css('padding-left', '18px');
            this.navcrollerLeft.show();
            this.navcrollerRight.show();

            activeTab = this.navContainer.children('.ui-tabs-selected');
            viewportWidth = this.navscroller.innerWidth();
            activeTabPosition = activeTab.position().left + parseInt(activeTab.innerWidth());

            if(activeTabPosition > viewportWidth) {
              var scrollStep = activeTabPosition - viewportWidth;
              scrollStep = Math.ceil(scrollStep/100) * -100;        
              this.scroll(scrollStep);
            } else {
                   this.restoreScrollState();
            }                 
         }            
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would have wished to override this single method by extending tabview component widget but it is not supported. So we should have our own tabview.js file with the above method modified.

This is done in primefaces 4.0 version, more, or less the changes will be same higher versions also.